# Selenium Driver Python is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Estoy tratando Scrapear otra Web , intente una solucion que me habian dado aqui(muy util ) de ejecutar el click desde JS , pero para esta nueva web no funciona adjunto codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/usa/nba/resultados/")
while True:
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-play']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="live-table"]/div[1]/div/div/a'))).click()
    Create = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="live-table"]/div[1]/div/div/a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Create)
    print("LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked")
driver.quit()
```

por lo que veo , el error que recibo es que se ejecuta una sola vez el click y luego me da el error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (749, 698). Other element would receive the click: ...

***Mi codigo quedo asi:***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/usa/nba/resultados/")


TIMEOUT = 5
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
while True:

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        #Click button
        WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event__more'))).click()
        print("LOAD MORE RESULT button clicked")
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Pero no funciona lamentablemente intente toda la semana , cambiando cosas , pero al parecer queda cargando y muchas veces no me devuelve el scroll , puede ser que la pagina tenga algun antibot o similar???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible solución puede ser :

Hacer `scroll` hacía abajo, `click` en el boton de "cargar más resultados" y repetir la simulación siempre que aparezca el boton. Entonces podemos crear un algoritmo que vaya haciendo `scroll` y que se detenga cuando no se pueda clickear más en el boton de carga.

```
TIMEOUT = 4
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
while True:

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        #Click button
        WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event__more'))).click()
        print("LOAD MORE RESULT button clicked")
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Una vez que termina el `while` podemos ver cuantos resultados se estan viendo en la pantalla:

```
browser.execute_script('''return document.getElementsByClassName('event__match event__match--static event__match--twoLine').length;''')
```

Si no coinciden los resultados, una solución sería agregar un `TIMEOUT` más grande, por ej 5.

Comment: Agregue una nueva edicion ya que no funciono

Comment: te sigue arrojando el mismo error?, acabo de copiar tal cual lo escribiste, solo le agregue la linea que te pedí que agregues al finalizar el _while_. y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Al final lo que sucedia es que a veces tardaba mucho en cargar todos los elementos en la pagina y terminaba ganandole al wait , o a veces no me devolvia la longitud de la pantalla para hacer el scroll porque continuaba cargando elementos.  Si a alguien le llega a servir , esto lo solucione con 2 cosas  Cambie a firefox como explorador
agregue el comando  **caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"**  Y ahora funciona perfecto